# How to "unhook" a hook from a module?

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to use the [`email_auto_login`](https://drupal.org/project/email_auto_login) module. However it implements a `hook_mail_alter` which I don't want.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function email_auto_login_mail_alter(&$message) {
  $user = user_load_by_mail($message['to']);

  // Don't add tokens for admin, anonymous or blocked.
  if (!isset($user->uid) || $user->uid == 1 || $user->status == 0) {
    return;
  }

  $token = _email_auto_login_generate_token($user);

  foreach ($message['body'] as &$body) {
    $body = _email_auto_login_add_token($body, $token);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to remove the hook without modifying the above code? I'm running Drupal7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it with [`hook_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) in your module. Simply test `$hook` and if it is the hook you don't want implemented, `unset($implementations['email_auto_login'])`.