# How do I unhook commerce_kickstart_blog_preprocess_node?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I am using Commerce Kickstart 2 with the their blog module, which includes a `hook_preprocess_node()` I need to short-circuit.

I looked at [How to "unhook" a hook from a module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99227/how-to-unhook-a-hook-from-a-module) and I thought I could put the following in a module.

```
function my_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'commerce_kickstart_blog_preprocess_node' && isset($implementations['commerce_kickstart_blog_preprocess_node'])) {
   unset($implementations['commerce_kickstart_blog_preprocess_node']);
  }
}
```

It doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`$implementations` is an array whose keys are the short name of the enabled modules; `$hook` is the name of the hook, without *hook_* nor the short name of the module.

You need to change your code to the following one.

```
function my_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'preprocess_node' && isset($implementations['commerce_kickstart_blog'])) {
   unset($implementations['commerce_kickstart_blog']);
  }
}
```

I assume the short name of your module is *my*; if it were *my_module*, then you would need to use the following code, since the hook is `hook_module_implements_alter()`.

```
function my_module_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'preprocess_node' && isset($implementations['commerce_kickstart_blog'])) {
   unset($implementations['commerce_kickstart_blog']);
  }
}
```